# How to Override CurrentThread.CurrentCulture for an application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, locale, globalization, currentculture

I have sharepoint application, that needs to be made support Globalization(multi language support). 
I am planning have a drop down box with list of languages.

Problem: By Default the CurrentCulture is en-US  as expected.Lets say the if user choose some other language(chinese) from the dropbox then I need to set CurrentCulture to chinese so that it can access corresponding resource xml file.

I tried overriding the currentculture based on user selection.But it is not getting effected for all the threads.

I tried setting in web.config  even that it don't work.

Please suggest how to change the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture for entire application(threads) based on user selected language.

Regards,
Archu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it the Sharepoint way:

http://www.denisstadler.com/sharepoint-2010/sharepoint-2010-publishing-feature/set-up-multilingual-support-in-sharepoint-2010/

If you really need to have control on the culture of the thread you can set them like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
    New CultureInfo("de")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    New CultureInfo("de-DE")
```

But only of you are spawning the threads yourself.

Comment: I tried setting is pro grammatically, the way you mentioned above.Again it will reset to default one.

Comment: You need to set it in each thread you are spawning. Sharepoint internal processes will get localisation from the site collection settings, web application settings etc